# Why is Google not ranking my page?

Tags: pagerank, google-ranking

After I re-designed my website, Google stoped ranking my page. I have no idea why.

I'm not banned from Google, because my website [is position #1 on the search](http://www.google.no/search?client=opera&rls=en-GB&q=norwegianfashion&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

And my META tags for robots look like this:

```
<meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
```

So why is [Google Page Rank Checker](http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php) not able to rate my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your site on the same tool and it gave a PageRank of 3.

But it doesn't matter. PageRank *is not* "ranking". You could have PR of 1 or 5 and it wouldn't really make a massive difference. I've said before, PageRank takes a trillion pages on the Internet and boils them all down to one of 10 integers.

You said yourself that your site appears in Google search, so unless you have experienced a significant drop in traffic, forget about PR and concentrate on making your site great.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is obviously being indexed by Google as [you can see here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.norwegianfashion.no) which is the main thing. I personally wouldn't worry too much about whether a 3rd party site can determin page-rank for your site, what matters is that it is available on Google and people can find it.

If you don't already have one, I'd suggest creating a [Google Webmasters account](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and using it's tools to verify if there is any problem. If there is, it should be indicated here. If not, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Yeah, I have an Google Webmaster account.

I'll not worry to much about this then. I just found it strange that my site no longer had any Page Rank.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why your site is not being ranked is because you may have had a large number of back links in a short period of time. Google does not like that and sees that as cheating, so it will not rank you.